# Mysql- Single Sequence Table for all Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a Database in Mysql from a Firebird Database. 
In the Database there is a Common Sequence table(Common_ID) which generates sequence for all tables (45 Tables in database). Some Tables are

```
Table1 = Sequence (ID Auto-increment)-The Common Sequence Table
Table2 = Process (Sequence, Process_Number(Unique), Category_Name)
Table2 = Tasks (Sequence, Barcode(Unique), Process_Number(sequence from Process Table), Product_Name)
```

This database already has more than 600,000 records.
One "Process" can have Many "Tasks".
My questions are:
What relationship should be between "Sequence" Table and "Process/Tasks" tables?
What relationship should be between Process Table and Tasks Table?
How do i insert in "Sequence" Table and use that "ID" in other Tables?

This is my first question and i am new to databases, so apologies for any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between Sequence and Process is one to one, the relation between Sequence and Task also is one to one (and the same with every other table which uses your sequence table in that way). The one side of this relation (Process resp. Task) don't need to exist.

The relation between Process and Task is one to many.

Your insert will be like

```
insert into Sequence values (0);
insert into Process values (last_insert_id(), ....);

insert into Sequence values (0);
insert into Task values (last_insert_id(), ....);
```

By the way, in your data model the table Process has two primary keys now. It might be a better data model when you use the process's sequence as a foreign key in Task.

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer. In sequence table i am also adding a field to store table name for which the sequence was generated and used, Now if two users are inserting in For example one in Process Table and another in task table, when i use Last_insert_ID() will there be any problem (Mix-up or something).

Comment: No problem. They have different database sessions. `last_insert_id()`gets the last inserted id in that session. Inserts in other sessions don't matter.

Comment: Sorry for Bothering you again. Should i use Stored Procedure and transactions or just simple inserts will do the Job. Also what should be the type of my tables (Innob, MyISAM etc) or just leave it what ever it is.

Comment: There is no need for stored procedures. You can simply insert the values. - Use InnoDB. MyISAM is not transaction-safe, and in the actual versions of MySQL InnoDB is as fast as MyISAM.

Comment: Sie hat mich gerettet. Danke ver viel